# Connecting and using a 4x4 matrix keyboard using RPi GPIO & Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm new to GPIO. I have got a 4x4 keypad for raspberry pi but I have no Idea how to connect it and how it can be programmed. When looking online I either see it connected to a Hat or get code with connections that don't make sense to me.
I'm using [this](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-size-product/public/27899.png?itok=zmmewvUT) keypad.

Help!

SideNote: I cannot open it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple 4x4 Matrix Keypad, it has total 8 wires, 4 rows and 4 columns. You can find the rows and columns by short circuit test using a Multimeter.

Simply place one probe of the meter on one of the wire and place other probe of all other wires one by one and press all the buttons and note down the combination, you'll find out which wire is connected to which row and column.

After doing so now you've to connect all these pins to 8 GPIOs(4 columns and 4 rows), now you'll have to use 4 pins as inputs(either rows or columns) and 4 as outputs. on all output pins you'd have to apply +5V one by one and check all input pins, if you find +5V on any of the input pins, that's your key(row#, col#).

ex:
If user presses key "1", this is first row and first column, when you apply +5V on first row the same voltage will appears at first column's pin.

Simply write a code which apply positive voltage at all 4 rows one at a time and then scan all the 4 columns repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pad4pi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pad4pi/1.0.0). It simplifies everything.

```
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio

# Setup Keypad
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

COL_PINS = [0,5,6,13] # BCM numbering
ROW_PINS = [19,26,20,21] # BCM numbering


factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)

keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(processKey)

def processKey(key):
  if (key=="1"):
    print("number")
  elif (key=="A"):
    print("letter")
```

Use **COL_PINS** & **ROW_PINS** to connecting keypad

Comment: There is no pin 0?

Comment: You should look at **BCM** pin layout @MatthewMiles